# How can I associate an icon to a file in a specific path in VS Code with the Material Icon Theme Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found "material-icon-theme.files.associations" can used for updating icons for a specific file. But this not working for /<sub_folder>/<file_name>. , but working for <sub_folder>/<file_name>.  and <file_name>..

How can make this work?

Tried and observed the below:

Updated setting.json for the current project workplace.

```json
"material-icon-theme.files.associations": {
  "<folder>/<sub_folder>/<file_name>.<extension>": "icon-name",
  "<sub_folder>/<file_name>.<extension>": "icon-name",
  "<file_name>.<extension>": "icon-name"
}
```

Icon are updated for `<sub_folder>/<file_name>.<extension>`  and `<file_name>.<extension>`, and any files that are more nested than that are not updating its icon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported by VS Code's file icon extension API (in which case the Material Icon Theme extension can't really do anything about it). The docs for file icon themes can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme#file-association). You can associate an icon to a `folderNames`, `folderNamesExpanded`, `languageIds`, `fileExtensions`, and `fileNames`, but not to anything more complicated than that.

There is a feature-request asking for the VS Code icon theme API to be expanded to allow globs, which what you're looking for would be a subset of. See [[icon-themes] Support for globs in file associations (Icon themes)
#12493](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12493). It even has [a PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/174286). Related to that issue ticket, in the Material Icon Theme issue tracker is [Use glob pattern for file / folder associations #330](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12493). I suggest that you give those issue tickets a thumbs up to show support for them. You can also subscribe to them to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".