How can I set the default viewer/editor to files associated with SQLite with any file extension?
I'm working with a project producing SQLite files with many different extensions (e.g. \*.mtsdb, \*.mtsdb.map, and many other \*.mtsdb.\*s).
And I've got a wonderful VSCode extension to view SQLite files called SQLite Viewer.
For each time I open a file with new extension, I have to configure its default editor/viewer to SQLite Viewer in the Open with ... in the right click menu.
How can I tell VSCode to open any files that I've associated its extension to SQLite in the file association with SQLite Viewer? (without set the Open with ... one by one for each extension)

Similar to the files.associations setting for associating language mode with filename patterns, there is a workbench.editorAssociations setting for associating editors (including custom editors) with filename patterns.

Substantially this is what I want. But is it possible to associate editor with language type, rather than filename pattern? Or is it possible to make it with glob? So that I only have to modify file associations for any new extensions/patterns (I have to adjust something else through file association, e.g. icon on explorer, not only editor).

@LibrarristShalinward no. as for your second question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664626/11107541
